# Sum (aggregate) a column without losing other columns

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a sentiment analysis and want to count the words in my corpora and at the same time keep the sentiment scores for each word. The sentiment score varies between -1 and 1. My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(words=c("danger", "here", "happy", "happy", "danger", "here" ) , senti_score =c(-0.8, 0, 0.7, 0.7, -0.8, 0))
```

| words | senti_score |
| --- | --- |
| danger | -0.8 |
| here | 0 |
| happy | 0.6 |
| happy | 0.6 |
| danger | -0.8 |
| here | 0 |

As you can see, each word corresponds to a specific sentiment score.

However, if I count the words with `count()` from the [dplyr-package](/questions/tagged/dplyr-package), I lose the column "senti_score".

```
library(dplyr)
wrd_cnt <- df %>%
  count(words, sort = TRUE )
```

Result looks like this:

| words | n |
| --- | --- |
| danger | 2 |
| here | 2 |
| happy | 2 |

After that I tried to stick it together with the `left_join()` from the [dplyr-package](/questions/tagged/dplyr-package):

```
wrd_cnt <- left_join(wrd_cnt, df, by = "words")
```

But as it seems, this disaggregates the data and the result looks like this:

| words | n | sneti_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| danger | 2 | -0.8 |
| danger | 2 | -0.8 |
| here | 2 | 0 |
| here | 2 | 0 |
| happy | 2 | 0.6 |
| happy | 2 | 0.6 |

Is there any way to stick the sentiment scores to the data frame and NOT disaggregate it at the same time? The result should look somehow like this:

| words | n | senti_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| danger | 2 | -0.8 |
| here | 2 | 0 |
| happy | 2 | 0.6 |

Can someone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can `group_by(word)` and then use `summarise()`. Then we have to aggregate the `senti_score` in some way, below I use `first()` to just use the first `senti_score` we could also use `mean()`, for both approaches the assumption is that each word has the same `senti_score()`. To get the count `n` we use `dplyr::n()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(words) %>% 
  summarise(senti_score = first(senti_score),
            n = n())

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   words  senti_score     n
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1 danger        -0.8     2
#> 2 happy          0.7     2
#> 3 here           0       2
```

Data from OP:

```r
df <- data.frame(words=c("danger", "here", "happy", "happy", "danger", "here" ) , senti_score =c(-0.8, 0, 0.7, 0.7, -0.8, 0))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With tidyverse tools, you often have to chain multiple functions to get to what you want, and this is perfectly fine. You have received an answer already, here's another approach that will get you to the same output:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(words) %>% 
  distinct()

   words senti_score n
1 danger        -0.8 2
2   here         0.0 2
3  happy         0.7 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `summarise` with `across` in order to preserve columns while still getting a count (or any other kind of numeric summary that you specify in `summarise`). Put the columns you want to preserve in the `across` function. Use `distinct` to remove all duplicated rows and `n` to count the number of rows:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(words) %>%
  summarise(across(senti_score), n = n()) %>%
  distinct()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   words [3]
#>   words  senti_score     n
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1 danger        -0.8     2
#> 2 happy          0.7     2
#> 3 here           0       2
```

If you want an output that is no longer grouped, use the `.groups` parameter in `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(words) %>%
  summarise(across(senti_score), n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  distinct()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   words  senti_score     n
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#> 1 danger        -0.8     2
#> 2 happy          0.7     2
#> 3 here           0       2
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R:

```
aggregate(n~., cbind(df,n = 1), sum)

   words senti_score n
1 danger        -0.8 2
2   here         0.0 2
3  happy         0.7 2

subset(data.frame(table(df)), Freq>0)

   words senti_score Freq
1 danger        -0.8    2
6   here           0    2
8  happy         0.7    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fcount` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fcount(df, words, senti_score)
   words senti_score N
1 danger        -0.8 2
2   here         0.0 2
3  happy         0.7 2
```

Or if more columns

```
fcountv(df, names(df))
   words senti_score N
1 danger        -0.8 2
2   here         0.0 2
3  happy         0.7 2
```